# Can I query and retrieve Documents' field values in Subcollection in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can I query and retrieve the Documents' field values in a subcollection?

Take the following for example:

```
States [Collection]
    State 1 [Document]
        Counties [Collection]
           County 1 [Document]
               British Population = 100 [Field]

           County 2 [Document]
               British Population = 200 [Field]

    State 2 [Document]
        Counties [Collection]

           County 1 [Document]
               British Population = 150 [Field]
```

How do I query the Documents with British Populations and retrieve the number of the `population`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the name of the `Counties` subcollection is the same within all `State` documents, to get the value of the "British Population" property, a [Firestore collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) is required. However, this will not work unless you have another property under your `Country` document that can help you create that query. In code, should look like this:

```
db.collectionGroup("Counties").whereEqualTo("nationality", "British").get()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                // ...
            }
        });
```

This is translated like this. Hey Firestore, give me all `Country` documents that exist in **all** `Countries` collections or subcollections where "nationality" is "British". So as you can see, I have added a new property named `nationality` and added the corresponding value as "British". Since all documents do contains such property, all documents will be returned.

Besides that, the "British Population" property can also be changed to "population". Now, inside the `onSuccess()`, you can query the `QuerySnapshot` object and get the value for the `population` property.